# Adobe premier pro how to replace a new mark in mark out video / audio from the previous one?

Tags: premiere, adobe

I am using Adobe Premiere Pro - 2021 for the first time. I know all the basics of it. But I want to replace an audio/video from a new marked in and out one.

Please see the image below for better understanding.

Read the number sequence for a better understanding. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can't you drag the audio icon from your source view (area 2 in your image) down to your timeline?